# Limit the number of characters in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to limit the number of displayed characters in `DropDownList` :

```
@Html.DropDownList("domaines", Model.Domaines, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "domaines", autocomplet = "autocomplet",maxlength = 21 })
```

this is the scenario :

1. **if the number of characters <= 18** : the whole word is displayed
2. **Else if number of characters > 18** : the first 18 characters will be displayed concatenated to an ellipsis (...).

How can I do this?

Comment: What type is `Domaines`?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez a collection of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare your model before you send it to the view. You [need to pass an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to `DropDownList()`, not your own type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329(v=vs.118).aspx). You can use the [`SelectList(IEnumerable, string, string)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx) for that.

How to truncate strings with ellipsis has been answered in [How do I truncate a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string) and [Ellipsis with C# (ending on a full word)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800962/ellipsis-with-c-sharp-ending-on-a-full-word).

In your controller:

```
// ... initialize model.

foreach (var domainModel in model.Domaines)
{
    // Assuming the display member you want to truncate is called `DisplayString`.
    // See linked questions for Truncate() implementation.
    domainModel.DisplayString = domainModel.DisplayString.Truncate(18); 
}

// Assuming the `Domaines` type has a `Value` member that indicates its value.
var selectList = new SelectList(model.Domaines, "Value", "DisplayString");

// Add a `public SelectList DomainSelectList { get; set; }` to your model.
model.DomainSelectList = selectList;

return View(model);
```

In your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("domaines", Model.DomainSelectList, new { ... })
```